# jquery tabulator auto reisze row height for nested grid

Tags: jquery, tabulator

I am using following Jquery Tabulator to build nested table.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Bind_tbl_MainTable();
});

function Bind_tbl_MainTable() {

    var data_fullset = [
        {
            "MainA": "5800", "MainB": "120", "MainC": "2",
            "MainD": [{ "ChildA": "5800(30)", "ChildB": 1, "ChildC": "Product 1", "ChildD": 1, "ChildE": 1, "ChildF": 1 },
            { "ChildA": "5800(30)", "ChildB": 2, "ChildC": "Product 2", "ChildD": 2, "ChildE": 2, "ChildF": 2 }]
        },
        {
            "MainA": "5800", "MainB": "120", "MainC": "1",
            "MainD": [{ "ChildA": "5800(30)", "ChildB": 1, "ChildC": "Product 1", "ChildD": 1, "ChildE": 1, "ChildF": 1 },
            { "ChildA": "5800(30)", "ChildB": 2, "ChildC": "Product 2", "ChildD": 2, "ChildA": 2, "ChildA": 2 }]
        }];

    var columns_child = [

        { title: "Child A", field: "ChildA", editor: true, cssClass: "center-align", headerSort: false, headerWordWrap: true, width: "fitData" },
        { title: "Child B", field: "ChildB", editor: false, cssClass: "center-align", headerSort: false, headerWordWrap: true, width: "6%" },
        { title: "Child C", field: "ChildC", editor: false, cssClass: "center-align", headerSort: false, headerWordWrap: true, width: "fitData" },

        { title: "Child D", field: "ChildD", editor: true, cssClass: "center-align", headerSort: false, headerWordWrap: true, width: "5%" },
        { title: "Child E", field: "ChildE", editor: false, cssClass: "center-align", headerSort: false, headerWordWrap: true, width: "5%" },
        { title: "Child F", field: "ChildF", editor: true, cssClass: "center-align", headerSort: false, headerWordWrap: true, width: "5%" },

    ];

    var columns_main = [
        { title: "Main A", field: "MainA", editor: true, cssClass: "center-align", headerSort: false, headerWordWrap: true, width: "4%" },
        { title: "Main B", field: "MainB", editor: true, cssClass: "center-align", headerSort: false, headerWordWrap: true, width: "4%" },
        { title: "Main C", field: "MainC", editor: true, cssClass: "center-align", headerSort: false, headerWordWrap: true, width: "4%" },
        {
            title: "Main D", field: "MainD", cssClass: "center-align", headerSort: false, width: "fitDataTable",
            formatter: function (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {

                var row = cell.getRow();
                var rowData = row.getData();
                var position = table.getRowPosition(row);

                var container = document.createElement("div");
                container.setAttribute("id", "tbl_Nested" + position);

                var nestedTable = new Tabulator(container, {
                    height: "100%",
                    width: "100%",
                    layout: "fitDataTable",
                    columns: columns_child,
                    data: cell.getValue(),
                });

                onRendered(function () {
                    cell.getElement().append(container);
                    //cell.setHeight("fitDataFill");
                });

                return "";
            }
        }
    ];


    // Create the main table
    var table = new Tabulator("#tbl_MainTable", {
        theme: "bootstrap",
        columns: columns_main,
        data: data_fullset,
        layout: "fitDataStretch",
        rowFormatter: function (row) {
            var cell_MainD = row.getCell("MainD").getElement();
            console.log("cell_MainD.style.height = " + cell_MainD.style.height);
            cell_MainD.style.height = "100%";
            console.log("cell_MainD.style.height = " + cell_MainD.style.height);
            //cell_MainD.css({ "height": "200px" });
            //// Normalize the height of the cell element
            //cell_MainD.style.height = "auto";
            //row.normalizeHeight();
            //cell_MainD.setHeight("fitDataFill");
            //cell_MainD.TestFrank();
        },
        height: "fitData"
    });
}
```

finally i received below table.

[image]

The problem is main table row height is not auto-resize based on nested table's height.
So when you look at that picture, you will find it difficult to see nested table.

But actually the nested table is already created.
Because when I resize the browser zoom in/out, it changed to below table.

[image]

So, my question is how to make my tabulator table auto-resize based on populated nested table's height?

I don't want to set hard coded value to height, just want to auto resize.

Thanks